# Is there a way to switch camera lens on the iPhone 7 Plus with AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession

I am developing an app that uses `AVCaptureSession` to capture photo. The iPhone 7 recently came out and I wants to make my app supports the both the telephoto lens and the wide angle lens for the iPhone 7 Plus. So far I haven't found anything that can set the different camera lens for the new iPhone 7 Plus.

So how can I make the switch between the wide angle lens and the telephoto lens with `AVCaptureSession`.